# TypeScript/Angular $q immediately resolve defer not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-promise

I have an Angular Service class that I created in TypeScript and I this service has a load method.  This particular service the list that it is loading is actually hard coded, so I don't need to load it from any backend service.  I would like the load method to return a promise though because I want to service to look like the other data services that I have in the class.

Here is the data service that I have

```
module MyApplication.Data {

    export interface IDestinationService {

        load(): ng.IPromise<Array<MyApplication.Models.Destination>>;

    }

    export class DestinationService implements IDestinationService {

        items: Array<MyApplication.Models.Destination>;

        constructor($http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService) {
            this.items = new Array<MyApplication.Models.Destination>();
            this.items.push(new MyApplication.Models.Destination());
            this.items.push(new MyApplication.Models.Destination());
            this.items[0].Id = 2;
            this.items[0].Description = 'Item 1';
            this.items[1].Id = 3;
            this.items[1].Description = 'Item 2';
        }

        load(): ng.IPromise<Array<MyApplication.Models.Destination>> {
            var defer = this.$q.defer();

            defer.resolve(this.items);

            return defer.promise;
        }

    }

}
```

From what I have read this should make the service work.  It will return a promise, but the promise will be immediately resolved when it is returned, so the then method should fire.

I have a Jasmine test class that looks like the following:

```
module MyApplication.Tests {

    describe('Data', () => {

        describe('Destination', () => {

            var $http: ng.IHttpService;
            var $httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService;
            var $q: ng.IQService;

            beforeEach(inject((_$http_: ng.IHttpService, _$httpBackend_: ng.IHttpBackendService, _$q_: ng.IQService) => {
                $http = _$http_;
                $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
                $q = _$q_;
            }));

            describe('', () => {
                var results: Array<MyApplication.Models.Destination>;

                beforeEach((done) => {
                    var service = new MyApplication.Data.DestinationService($http, $q);
                    service.load()
                        .then((result) => {
                            results = result;
                            done();
                        });
                });

                it('Returns Planning Brokers list', () => {
                    expect(results.length).toBe(2);
                });

            });

        });

    });

}
```

But when I run this test I'm getting an Async timeout error from Jasmine because the then method is never firing.  How can I get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the second `describe` and `beforeEach` blocks. Resolve the promise using `rootScope.$digest` and restructure your test code like this:

```
describe('Data', () => {

    describe('Destination', () => {

        var $http: ng.IHttpService;
        var $httpBackend: ng.IHttpBackendService;
        var $q: ng.IQService;

        beforeEach(inject((_$http_: ng.IHttpService, _$httpBackend_: ng.IHttpBackendService, _$q_: ng.IQService) => {
            $http = _$http_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $q = _$q_;
        }));

        it('Returns Planning Brokers list', () => {
            var results: Array<MyApplication.Models.Destination>;

            var service = new MyApplication.Data.DestinationService($http, $q);
            service.load().then((results) => {
                expect(results.length).toBe(2);
            });

            $rootScope.$digest();
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You first example didn't work (the restructuring part was fine, but it still didn't resolve the promise.  But once I added the $digest it did work.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry I was thinking of es6 promises for the first example. I'll remove it.